# What <has><had> he done? vs What did he do?

Tags: reported-speech

I want to ask. In below conversation, which one I should use?

> A : Why do you hate him ? ( What has he done / what did he do ) to you ?" >>
>
> B : Sorry what did you say?
>
> A : I asked you what ( had he done / has he done/ did he do )?"

Comment: If you're going to include auxiliary ***to have***, the most natural phrasing is *I asked you what **he had** done* (where subject/verb are inverted in the "question" format *What **had he** done?*). By the same token, *I asked you what he did* (lose the quotes and question marks for that; it's just a straightforward ***assertion***).

Answer (score 0):

**Interrogative sentence(direct)**

When/Where/What/How/why/Who + Verb(V) + Subject(S) + ?

For example:

Where are you?, Where did he go?, Who are you?

**Interrogative sentence(indirect)**

S + V + When/Where/What/How/why/Who S + V

For example:

I asked him when he went there.

She asked me why I was late.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between these forms is whether there is a lasting effect.

From the ["education first" website](https://www.ef.edu/english-resources/english-grammar/present-perfect/):

> The present perfect is used to indicate a link between the present and
> the past. The time of the action is before now but not specified, and
> we are often more interested in the result than in the action itself.

If an action in the past is still impacting how one feels now, then present perfect is the right form.

> What has he done that makes you still feel this way?

Using simple past fits the case, when, for example, one presents an anecdote about an event where someone did something surprising — but it has no bearing on the current state of the world.

> What did he do that the other guests found so surprising?

Answer (score 0):

You can use either the present perfect (**What has he done?**) or the simple past tense (**What did he do**?)

**I asked you what he had done** (NOT 'what had he done). When the question ('What had he done') is part of a long sentence ('I asked...'), it loses the normal question word order.

Direct: I asked you 'What did he do?'

Indirect: I asked you what he had done.